# How to return long from a method when the return value is greater than long?

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a problem in Topcoder, where I need to find the number of rectangles(excluding squares) when the width and length are provided. My code works perfect for all test cases, but for one final test case, ie `592X964` I need to return `81508708664` , which is greater than `2^32-1` , which is greater than the value long can hold, but the compiler demands the value must be returned in `long` . I've added the problem statement and my code below, kindly go through, and let me know if its possible to return the above value using long in java.

```
    /*
Problem Statement
    
Given the width and height of a rectangular grid, return the total number of rectangles (NOT counting squares) that can be found on this grid.
For example, width = 3, height = 3 (see diagram below):
 __ __ __
|__|__|__|
|__|__|__|
|__|__|__|
In this grid, there are 4 2x3 rectangles, 6 1x3 rectangles and 12 1x2 rectangles. Thus there is a total of 4 + 6 + 12 = 22 rectangles. Note we don't count 1x1, 2x2 and 3x3 rectangles because they are squares.
Definition
    
Class:
RectangularGrid
Method:
countRectangles
Parameters:
int, int
Returns:
long
Method signature:
long countRectangles(int width, int height)
(be sure your method is public)
Limits
    
Time limit (s):
2.000
Memory limit (MB):
64
Notes
-
rectangles with equals sides (squares) should not be counted.
Constraints
-
width and height will be between 1 and 1000 inclusive.
Examples
0)

    
3
3
Returns: 22
See above
1)

    
5
2
Returns: 31
 __ __ __ __ __
|__|__|__|__|__|
|__|__|__|__|__|
In this grid, there is one 2x5 rectangle, 2 2x4 rectangles, 2 1x5 rectangles, 3 2x3 rectangles, 4 1x4 rectangles, 6 1x3 rectangles and 13 1x2 rectangles. Thus there is a total of 1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 + 13 = 31 rectangles.
2)

    
10
10
Returns: 2640

3)

    
1
1
Returns: 0

4)

    
592
964
Returns: 81508708664

This problem statement is the exclusive and proprietary property of TopCoder, Inc. Any unauthorized use or reproduction of this information without the prior written consent of TopCoder, Inc. is strictly prohibited. (c)2003, TopCoder, Inc. All rights reserved.
*/
public class RectangularGrid
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(countRectangles(592,964));
    }

    public static long countRectangles(int m, int n)
    {
        long tot_rect = (long)(((m*m)+m)*((n*n)+n))/4;
        long tot_square = 0;
        boolean status = true;

        while(status)
        {
            if(m>0 && n>0)
            {
                tot_square+=(long)m*n;
                --m;
                --n;
            }
            else
            {
                status = false;
            }

        }


        return tot_rect-tot_square;
    }
}
```

Comment: A `long` is 2^63-1.

Comment: Why not use `BigDecimal`, assuming you really can't store the value in a `long` (which you can)?

Comment: A `long` is 64 bits so it can hold values between -2^63 and 2^63 - 1; your idea that it cannot hold values greater than 2^32 - 1 is wrong.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, I read it wrong :/

Comment: *"but the compiler demands the value must be returned in `long`"* Aside from the fact that `long`'s max positive value is 2^64-1, not 2^32-1, that statement doesn't make sense. The *compiler* is in no position to demand that you use a `long`. Perhaps an interface or some such, but not the compiler.

Comment: @Jesper , running this code returns garbage values, I cant see why it does that if the value can be hold by long . :/

Comment: Then something else in your code is wrong - it's definitely not because a `long` cannot hold values larger than 2^32 - 1, because that's not true... You could make `m` and `n` `long` instead of `int`, because when you are calculating `tot_rect` you are using `int` arithmetic and casting the result to `long`, but overflow may already have happened because you are calculating using `int` instead of `long`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> running this code returns garbage values, I cant see why it does that if the value can be hold by long

Because you're doing `int` multiplication:

```
public static long countRectangles(int m, int n)
// Note ---------------------------^^^----^^^
{
    long tot_rect = (long)(((m*m)+m)*((n*n)+n))/4;
    // Note -----------------^^^-------^^^
```

If you want those to use `long`, you'll need casts:

```
public static long countRectangles(int m, int n)
{
    long tot_rect = ((((long)m*m)+m)*(((long)n*n)+n))/4;
    // Note -----------^^^^^^----------^^^^^^
```

Casting the end result doesn't do anything for losses in intermediate results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem, an explanation how it solves would be much helpful . Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Long is 8 bytes which means its range is -2^63 to 2^63 - 1; So it is by far greater then 2^32-1. It is Integer type that is 4 bytes and its range is -2^31 to 2^31-1. So you are perfectly fine with long as you are within range.